# How to fix error 'Writing 0 cols but got 4 aliases' in python using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I'm trying to save some data scraped using selenium to CSV file using pandas, but I'm getting this error and I don't know what's the problem.

I tried to use `header=False` instead of the `header=['','','','']`,
it works without error but gave me an empty CSV file.

Error:

```
full_datas = list(zip(d_links, d_title, d_price, d_num))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=full_datas)
df.to_csv('cc.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False, header=['Links','Title,','Price','PNum'])
```

Empty csv:

```
full_datas = list(zip(d_links, d_title, d_price, d_num))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=full_datas)
df.to_csv('cc.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False, header=False)
```

I'm expecting a CSV file with my data on it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/data/some/urls.py", line 90, in <module>
    df.to_csv('cc.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False, header=['Links','Title,','Price','PNum'])

  File "C:\Users\Iwillsolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3228, in to_csv
    formatter.save()

  File "C:\Users\Iwillsolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 202, in save
    self._save()

  File "C:\Users\Iwillsolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 310, in _save
    self._save_header()

  File "C:\Users\Iwillsolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 242, in _save_header
    "aliases".format(ncols=len(cols), nalias=len(header))
ValueError: Writing 0 cols but got 4 aliases
```

Comment: Have you checked if df contains the expected data before saving it to the file?

Comment: after checking the df print [] empty list, and full_datas print empty list also
put printing the lists in full_datas print right values, what could be the problem here

Comment: can we see the code that generates the lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes the list might be empty so i managed to fix it by using zip_longest

thank you guys for trying to help :)